# jquery code with erratic behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

In one of the pages of my web application, I have the follow code:

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${usuarios}">
    <c:forEach var="auth" items="${autorizacoes}">
        <script>
            $("#cb_001_${user.id}").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                  url: "cad_autorizacao.html",
                  data: { usuario: "${user.id}", autorizacao: "${auth.nome}" },
                  cache: false
                }).done(function(data) {
                    $("#result_2").show();
                    $("#result_2").empty().append( data );
                    $("#result_2").hide(3000);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

which act over this html code:

```
    <div class="row autorizacoes" id="row_001_${item.id}">
        <table class="bordered">
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="item_auth" items="${autorizacoes}">
                        <c:set var="isChecked" value="${false}"/>
                <c:forEach var="user_auth" items="${item.autorizacoes}">
                        <c:if test="${user_auth.nome == item_auth.nome}">  <!-- here compare according ID or any unique attribute -->
                            <c:set var="isChecked" value="${true}"/>
                        </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="${item_auth.nome}" <c:if test="${isChecked}">checked="checked"</c:if> id="cb_001_${item.id}"/>${item_auth.nome}
                    </td>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

basicly, this code capture the click in a list of checkbox and send a requisition to server with two data: the user and an authorization. The problem is: when I click in the first checkbox, several authorizations are writen in the database, and when I click in the others checkbox, nothing happens.

Someone can see any problem with this code?

Comment: Could you post the javascript and HTML code created by the template, instead of the template code? It would help.

Comment: Is this in JSP? Might help to use that tag also

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so ended solving my problem after take the sugestion from Oscar Paz of give a look in the code created by the template. After all, I only made one little change in the ID of checkbox, for include the id from autorization, not so the id from user.